# What character may cause to escape the left or right part of STRING?

Tags: php

## Question 1)

in PHP when we check:

```
  dir1/dir2/../file.txt  ====(this is same as)=====>   dir1/file.txt
```

is something like this possible:

```
  file_get_contents('/home/path/' . $_GET['evil']. '/file.txt');
```

if hacker set `$evil` to like: `\0` or `../` (I  want to know if there are real ones) that causes  PHP to escape right part OF PATH (i know to how to escape left part of path), so, hacker accessed like this:

```
 '/home/path/'. 'eviltfile.php?\0'. '/file.txt'`  //and thus file.txt was ignored
```

## Question 2)

I have another question about general strings (not file-path), so, if there is any `evil_character` that causes PHP to escape left part or right STRING, like this:

```
$evil = '../red apple\0';
$message = 'green ' . $evil. ' banana';
print($message ) ==============> red apple
```

p.s. Dont need answers for old php versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should canonicalize input data before a validating and a processing.

**Question 1)**

You should use canonical functions for handling files, PHP has some functions for this purpose, for example: [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) or [realpath](http://php.net/manual/es/function.realpath.php). Those functions canonicalizes file paths to avoid behaviours like you talked about, for example, if an attacker write something like this `..?param=../../path/file`, those functions convert the string in something like this `/path/file`.

**Question 2)**

You should use canonical functions for input data, PHP doesn't have many options in my oppinion, so I think a good option is [OWASP ESAPI for PHP](https://code.google.com/archive/p/owasp-esapi-php/). This API's functions convert every character to mimimal expression, so you can validate or process a sanitized input data and minimizing strange behaviours on your code.

I hope this information helps you.

Comment: hmrojas, thanks but none of the questions was answered really. You answered the question "how to avoid/safeguard" and I asked different question, for which I needed answer. however, thnks!